# AUCTeX parsing question

Tags: auctex

I have a problem with AUCTeX loading the correct hooks with a Beamer file.

If my file contains line breaks in the `documentclass` line, the style hooks are not loaded. (Thus I have no `frame`s in my AUCTeX environments, and other commands are also unavailable.) For instance:

```latex
\documentclass[14pt,
  handout, % no transitions
  xcolor=svgnames]
  {beamer}
```

But if there are indeed **no** breaks, the style hooks are correctly loaded. For instance:

```latex
\documentclass[handout,xcolor=svgnames]{beamer}
```

Note that both ways are correct in LaTeX, but the first one enhances readability.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you mean that the *former* enhances readability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regexp matching `\documentclass` commands is contained in `LaTeX-auto-minimal-regexp-list`.  It does accept breaks withing optional arguments, but it expects the closing square bracket be followed by the opening curly bracket.  You can either write

```latex
\documentclass[14pt,
  handout, % no transitions
  xcolor=svgnames
  ]{beamer}
```

in your document or change the regexp in order to accept a newline after the closing square bracket.  I think the former is easier to do.